# Аргументы функции setAlignment() в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Можете объяснить что должны принимать аргументы функции

> setAlignment(Union, Qt_Alignment=None, Qt_AlignmentFlag=None):

Зарание спасибо.

Comment: Для какого типа?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим на описание метода `PyQt5`:

```
# real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
def setAlignment(self, Union, Qt_Alignment=None, Qt_AlignmentFlag=None):
    """ setAlignment(self, Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag]) """
    pass
```

Тут показывается что реальная сигнатура, описанная в `__doc__` имеет один параметр (это подтверждается при попытке передать больше одного параметра в функцию), который либо `Qt.Alignment`, либо `Qt.AlignmentFlag`.

Поэтому, параметры `Union, Qt_Alignment=None, Qt_AlignmentFlag=None` на самом деле это один параметр.

Дополнительное подтверждение можно увидеть если посмотреть [описание этого же метода в документации самой Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#alignment-prop):

```
void setAlignment(Qt::Alignment)
```

И тут может возникнуть вопрос:

> Почему в PyQt5 этот параметр описывается как Union[Qt.Alignment,
> Qt.AlignmentFlag], а в оригинальной документации просто Qt::Alignment?

Для ответа на вопрос нужно смотреть тоже в документации Qt для перечисления [Qt::Alignment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum):

```
enum Qt::AlignmentFlag
flags Qt::Alignment
```

`Qt::Alignment` это набор флагов `Qt::AlignmentFlag`: `Qt::AlignLeft`, `Qt::AlignRight` и т.п., другими словами в `Qt::Alignment` может передавать конкретный флаг или сразу несколько: например флаг `Qt::AlignCenter` строится из флагов `Qt::AlignVCenter` и `Qt::AlignHCenter`.

Чтобы составить список флагов их нужно перечислять через битовый `или` – оператор `|`:

```
my_align_center = Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter
```

А `Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag]` это указание одной из перечисленных вариаций в параметре, что сходится с тем, что выше написал.

Я объяснил почему указывается `Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag]` в описании параметра `setAlignment`.

Теперь, немного практики.

---

Ниже [привожу пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/bc58eef5cde8692edeb1e43dc0d38ec0c3b92e0b/qt_alignment_qlabel.py) использования `Alignment`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QApplication, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


def create_label(alignment):
    label = QLabel('Test')
    label.setFixedSize(40, 40)
    label.setFrameStyle(QLabel.Box)
    label.setAlignment(alignment)

    return label


app = QApplication([])

layout = QGridLayout()
layout.addWidget(create_label(Qt.AlignLeft), 0, 0)
layout.addWidget(create_label(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignBottom), 0, 1)
layout.addWidget(create_label(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter), 0, 2)
layout.addWidget(create_label(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop), 0, 3)
layout.addWidget(create_label(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop), 0, 4)
layout.addWidget(create_label(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter), 0, 5)

w = QWidget()
w.setLayout(layout)
w.show()

app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете пожалуйста еще раз рассказать в чем разница между AlignmentFlag и Alignment

Comment: AlignmentFlag -- конкретный флаг, например Left. Alignment -- набор флагов от одного и больше